# JQuery Dialog on table row

Tags: c#, jquery, razor

I am using c# and razor to produce a list of invoices. Each invoice is a table row and has a huge list of notes against it. To avoid a massive amount of space between rows, I want to hide the notes and allow a pop to view it. It is currently:

```
 <td>
@foreach (var invoiceLine in invoice.InvoiceLines)
                {
                    <p>
                        <strong>@invoiceLine.Date.ToShortDateString() @invoiceLine.Username</strong> <br />
                        @Html.Raw(invoiceLine.Notes.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")) 
                        @Html.Raw((invoiceLine.DueDate.HasValue ? "<br /><strong>Follow up:</strong> " + invoiceLine.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : "")) 
                        @Html.Raw(invoiceLine.Completed ? "<br /><strong>Completed</strong>" : "")
                    </p>
                }
```

So what I want to do is to add the popup using jquery:

```
$(function () {

$('#clickMe').click(function (event) {
    var mytext = $('#myText').val();

    $('<div id="dialog">' + mytext + '</div>').appendTo('body');
    event.preventDefault();

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $("#dialog").hide();
        }
    });
}); //close click
```

});

Then modify my code:

```
<td>
            <h3 id="clickMe">Open Notes</h3>
               <textarea cols="1" rows="75" id="myText" style="display:none">
                @foreach (var invoiceLine in invoice.InvoiceLines)
                {
                    <p>
                        <strong>@invoiceLine.Date.ToShortDateString() @invoiceLine.Username</strong> <br />
                        @Html.Raw(invoiceLine.Notes.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")) 
                        @Html.Raw((invoiceLine.DueDate.HasValue ? "<br /><strong>Follow up:</strong> " + invoiceLine.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : "")) 
                        @Html.Raw(invoiceLine.Completed ? "<br /><strong>Completed</strong>" : "")
                    </p>
                }
                </textarea>
            </td>
```

First problem is, that only the first row appears. I presume because my id is the same all the way down?

How do I make the dialog open for each row?

I am a newb at c# and js btw :)

Comment: Is that click me meant to be in each row? If so then you need to put it inside the loop for a start.

Comment: It is meant to be for each row. The loop you see is a nested loop. The loop here is for the details for build the comment paragraph, in where there can be many notes per row.

Answer (score 0):

First: The textarea makes no sense at all.

Then change the parts like this. See it working in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/2BbmY/1/).

**HTML**

```
<td>
@foreach (var invoiceLine in invoice.InvoiceLines)
{

    <p>
        <strong>@invoiceLine.Date.ToShortDateString() @invoiceLine.Username</strong> <br />
        @Html.Raw((invoiceLine.DueDate.HasValue ? "<br /><strong>Follow up:</strong> " + invoiceLine.DueDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : "")) 
        @Html.Raw(invoiceLine.Completed ? "<br /><strong>Completed</strong>" : "")

        <h3 class="notesClick">Open Notes</h3>
        <div class="notesHtml" style="display:none">
          @Html.Raw(invoiceLine.Notes.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")) 
        </div>

    </p>
}
</td>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $('.notesClick').click(function(event) {
        var notes = $(event.currentTarget).next('.notesHtml');
        $("<div>").html(notes.html()).dialog();
    });

});​
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. The above example does not seem to work. I am not sure if its my version of jquery, which is 1.7?

Comment: That should work, look at my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/2BbmY/1/ Maybe you have a mistake in your code somewhere. Your version should be fine.

Comment: I had to download jquery-ui again. There may have been a problem with the version I had. This works perfectly.

Comment: Then you could set this answer as accepted so others can see that and how this is solved. ;)